# Problema ao subir build de app para Apple

Tags: ios, app, build, apple, phonegap-buillder

Estou tentando subir a build do meu aplicativo com o formato .ipa.

estou utilizando o application loader para subir essas informações. 
O desenvolvimento do app está sendo feito em phonegap.

Quando tento importar para a apple, o application loader me reporta a seguinte mensagem abaixo:

```
    WARNING ITMS-90339: "Deprecated Info.plist Key. The Info.plist 
contains a key 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' in bundle MyApp [Myapp.app] 
that will soon be unsupported. Remove the key, rebuild your app and resubmit."
```

Vocês já pegaram esse erro ?

Comment: Aqui tem mais informações: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationexitsonsuspend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução

Instalei o XCODE e subi a build por lá.
Acredito que isso seja uma solução para quem está com o mesmo erro usando o application Loader.